# How to obtain the binomial expansion of $\sqrt[4]{1+x}+\sqrt[4]{1-x} $ up to the term containing $x^2 $?

Tags: binomial-theorem

The question requires me to obtain the binomial expansion of 
$$\sqrt[4]{1+x}+\sqrt[4]{1-x} $$
up to term containing $x^2$.

My initial attempt involved finding the binomial expansion of each side up to the term with $x^2$ which resulted in:

$$ 1+\frac{x}{4}-\frac{3}{32}x^2+\dots $$
and

$$ 1-\frac{x}{4}-\frac{3}{32}x^2+\dots $$
and then I thought of simply adding the expansions but then I wondered if it was possible since each side is infinite. Is it okay to add both sides since I'm only finding terms up to the one containing $x^2$?

Comment: what is infinite here???

Comment: It's OK to add those power series term by term. In general, most formal operations on power series are correct when everything converges. (Clearly that general idea needs a careful statement and proof.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add them because the remainder in both cases is $o(x^2)$ (see [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)):
$$\sqrt[4]{1\pm x}=1\pm \frac{x}{4}-\frac{3}{32}x^2+o(x^2).$$
Hence
$$\sqrt[4]{1+x}+\sqrt[4]{1-x}=2-\frac{3}{16}x^2+o(x^2).$$